# ViewModel DropDownList and HTTP Post Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having some issues with the Post Controller for my Create Action.  Below is my models, Round, Material,MaterialShape, RawMaterial.  My Main objective is to add Round object to the database.

```
public class Material
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Material")]
    public string MaterialName { get; set; }
}
```

Abstract Class for Material Shape

```
 public abstract class MaterialShape
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
}
```

Round Inherited Class from MaterialShape

```
  [Table("Rounds")]
public class Round : MaterialShape
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Outside Diameter")]
    public double OuterDiameter { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the View Model I created to bring all the Materials to the view.  I used an IEnumerable to bring all the different Materials from the database.  I also have included an MaterialId to hold my selected item.

```
 public class VMRoundMaterial
{
    public Round Round { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Material")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Materials  { get; set; }

    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Create Action

```
  public ActionResult Create()
      {
        var model = new VMRoundMaterial();
        using (var db = new DbContext())
        {
            model.Materials = db.Materials.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                Text = x.MaterialName
            });
        } 
        return View(model);
    }
```

Create View

```
@model SetupSheet.Models.ViewModel.VMRoundMaterial

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Round</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Round.OuterDiameter, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Round.OuterDiameter)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Round.OuterDiameter)


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Materials, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MaterialId, Model.Materials)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  }

  <div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")  
  </div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
```

[image: Round Create View with Combobox from Database]

As you can see I accomplished the getting the list to the database.  I am having issues with converting the Viewmodel back to my Datamodel in the Create [Post] Action.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(VMRoundMaterial viewmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Round roundmaterial = new Round();

                roundmaterial.OuterDiameter = viewmodel.Round.OuterDiameter;
                roundmaterial.Material.ID = viewmodel.MaterialId;
                db.Rounds.Add(roundmaterial);
                db.SaveChanges();
            } 

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

[image: Viewmodel null]
My [HttpPost] is not working correctly.  Did I set it up correctly?  What about the DropDownListFor parameters are set up correctly?  Did I convert my selecteditem correctly to the Round object? The ModelState.IsValid is being returned false for some reason.  What could be be causing this?
The code is failing on

```
roundmaterial.Material.ID = viewmodel.MaterialId;
```

The database connection is working, but I'm not getting in results.  I am open to other strategies to find one that works.

jstadnicki proposed solution

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ModelDTO viewmodel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                Round roundmaterial = new Round();

                roundmaterial.OuterDiameter = viewmodel.Round.OuterDiameter;
                roundmaterial.Material.ID = viewmodel.MaterialId;

                db.Rounds.Add(roundmaterial);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

[image: ModelDTO Values]

[image: ModelState.IsValid = "false"]

I understand why to you want to use the ModelDTO, but I'm still having problems.

The ModelState is still false.  I think we are still missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelState` is invalid because your using a data model in your view model (`Round`) and not posting back values for the required `Material` property.

Generally, view models for editing data should not include properties which are data models, and your view should be

```
public class VMRoundMaterial
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Outside Diameter")]
    public double OuterDiameter { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Material")]
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Materials  { get; set; }
}
```

Note also your display attribute needs to be on `int MaterialId`,  not `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Materials` in order to create a label associated with `MaterialId` (currently, clicking on the 'label' will not set focus to the `<select>` element). Then the view will be

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.OuterDiameter)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OuterDiameter)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OuterDiameter)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaterialId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MaterialId, Model.Materials)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MaterialId)
```

Side note: Your use of `roundmaterial.Material.ID = viewmodel.MaterialId;` in the POST method will likely throw a `NullReferenceException` since you have not initialized property `Material`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you problem correctly: try to change the VMRoundMaterial in post method to ModelDTO, where modeldto is defined like this:

```
public class ModelDTO 
{
    public Round Round {get;set;}
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
}
```

Check now if you will get properly hydrated model.

Comment: ModelDTO in this instance is Round.  Round is inherited from MaterialShape.  MaterialShape has a property of Material of Material type.  See above.  Are you suggesting I use MaterialID as the key in the datamodel instead of the material type/object.  Maybe my objects are the problem.

Comment: You will not get the collection of materials. ViewModel != DTO models. Notice that on the HTML you find only one <input> with MaterialD and you are getting it, as shown on the screen shot. In order to get the list of materials you need to re-generate it by your self. The code is correct.

Comment: So regeneration the list from the database and then save it as a material type?  Why is the ModelState.IsValid = "false"?

Comment: ModelState is a surprise for me. But, please change the input model in controller to the one I proposed and updated in my answer. Notice that is contains only the data that will be send by the form displayed on the page. Check if it will be valid. 
Please keep in mind that the model you are using to display data (aka: ViewModel) and the model that are being sent to you in controllers (aka: Data Transfers Objects ~DTO~) are in most cases different.